# Rendering static HTML files from Node/Express views as part of build process

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, pug

Not sure if my terminology is correct here. I have a Node/Express server, serving up Jade template files to an AngularJS app.

For my live deployment I need to be running the app in Apache / static files, rather than the dynamic Jade views.

Are there any packages that I can point at my views/partials folders and render the Jade templates into HTML files, as part of my build process? (I'm using Gulp if it can be integrated into that too).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gulp-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade), as long your templates do not use any dynamic data that needs to come from node.

But your motivation seems strange. Are you only using node.js as a convenient local webserver and your live deployment will still use angular? In that case, just serve the templates statically with Apache and let angular handle the rendering.

Comment: Angular can render Jade templates? The project is going to an enterprise solution and installing Node isn't an option, really just able to run client-side code here sadly.